# Hadoop Job silent fail

Tags: java, hadoop

I configure my job and than do

```
job.waitForCompletion(true);
if (job.isSuccessful()) {
```

Where I don't get any exceptions but `job.isSuccessful() == false`. And I even haven't sources to debug that dammit job.

**Question:** How can I find more info? How to find logs? How to attach sources?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at the jobtracker UI and monitoring the stack trace.

Comment: I'm newcomer with Hadoop. Can you explain me pls

Comment: Try writing the if condition before the job.waitForCompletion(true);

Comment: what that will change? Also it fails only in my unit tests. I mean in real app it works good

Comment: Which distribution of hadoop are you using?.

Comment: <IP>:50030,  will allow you to monitor the job progress.

Comment: that's the problem - hadoop doesn't throw any error. My application throws it - I mean if job isn't successful I throw RuntimeError.

Comment: can you suggest how to attach sources? Than I'll provide a stack trace. I tried this http://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.5/mr.html but with no result